# Excel vba - unprotect and protect while executing macro's

Tags: excel, vba, macros, password-protection

My spreadsheet hides and shows multiple rows by clicking buttons. As the spreadsheet is password protected any macro should apply password, then runs hide/show and finally set password again. This is how its look like.

```
Sub Macro1()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="abc"
Rows("12:16").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="abc"
End Sub


Sub Macro2()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="abc"
Rows("12:16").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="abc"
End Sub

Sub Macro3()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="abc"
Rows("20:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="abc"
End Sub


Sub Macro4()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="abc"
Rows("20:24").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="abc"
End Sub
```

Script works fine, but I have 16 sections which require 32 macro's. It still works fine but I wonder if there would be an easier way, requiring only 1 line for applying and 1x for setting the password.

Thank you for your comments.

Dennis
The Netherlands

Comment: What about just creating 2 procedures? 1 with all the false gathered and 1 with all the true gathered, since the password is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Macro1
    HideIt Rows("12:16"),  True
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
    HideIt Rows("12:16"),  False
End Sub

Sub HideRows(rng As Range, HideIt as Boolean)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="abc"
    rng.EntireRow.Hidden = HideIt
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="abc"
End Sub
```

If you could name your buttons with something which would enable to to translate the names to a range and true/False, you could link them all to a single Sub and use Application.Caller to get the name of the calling button and extract the parameters from that.

**EDIT:**

OK here's a very simple example: add two "forms" buttons to your worksheet and name one "btn_12_5_H" and the other "btn_12_5_S".

Here's how you name each button:

1. Select the button via a right-click
2. Enter the name in the "name" box in the formula bar and **press Enter**

[image]

Link both buttons to the Sub below (right-click button >> Assign macro):

```
Sub ShowHideRows()

    Dim arr

    'split the calling button name into an array
    '  (array will be zero-based)
    arr = Split(Application.Caller, "_")

    '**EDIT** check array is expected size...
    If UBound(arr) <> 3 Then Exit Sub 

    If IsNumeric(arr(1)) and IsNumeric(arr(2)) Then
        With Me  'if the code is in the sheet module, else "ActiveSheet"
            .Unprotect Password:="abc"

            'arr(1) determines start row
            'arr(2) determines # of rows
            'arr(3) determines if rows are hidden or not
            .Cells(arr(1), 1).Resize(arr(2), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = (arr(3) = "H")
            .Protect Password:="abc"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

Just for completeness, note that you can also add arguments directly to the `OnAction` (i.e. when you right-click the button an select "Assign macro")

For example you can use something like:

```
Book1!'ShowHideRows2 12,TRUE'
```

Note use of single quotes around the whole thing.  The called sub might look something like (very basic example to demonstrate that the arguments were properly passed):

```
Sub ShowHideRows2(rownum, HideIt)
    Debug.Print rownum, HideIt
End Sub
```

Note that because the Sub has parameters it won't show up in the "Assign macro" list and you have to type it in.

Comment: You could pass in the address instead of the entire range.

Comment: Zev, indeed, I do for my practical work. However for this example I just use plain row numers.

Comment: Tim, thanks for explanation. But though I'm not so bad in Excel building, I am in VBA programming.

Would you mind giving an example on how to define a button and using Application.Caller. The latter is unknown to me yet.

Comment: Tim, this is a very interesting solution. I only need to figure out how to modify script to enable use for different number of rows. 

My sheet consists of 16 sections and 8 contain 5 rows, 4 20 rows and 4 50 rows. Probably I need to define an additional parameter which can be called from the button name.

So "btn_12_H" should be extended to "btn_12_H_5" and another one may be called "btn_36_H_20". First will hide/show 5 rows from row 12, second will hide/show 20 rows starting at 36.

If you could suggest how to do this, it would be great.

Dennis

Comment: Updated the example above.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll proceed tomorrow.

Denins

Comment: Well, I've not been very succsful up to now and I'm a bit confused. There are 2 ways of creating a button. Plain 'Form' and through Activex. The latter allows adding a name, the first does not. For better understanding, I need to use form buttons of 5 mm size, presenting a 'plus' sign or a 'minus' sign.

So I'm embaressed to ask, nu how do I connect proper script to those buttons ?

Thanks, Dennis

Comment: You can name your Forms buttons.  See my edits above

Comment: Oops, didn't realize this way of naming buttons ! I got both buttons properly named, assigned macro and saved spreadsheet as .xslm . Nonetheless macro is not executed.
Macro itself is placed on VBA page from Sheet1 (which is called 'Blad1' in Dutch). I wonder if included JPG may give an idea how it's build now.
!(https://www.mupload.nl/img/gvqdczehyzwcn.jpg)

Comment: If you put a Msgbox call in the macro does it run when you click the buttons?

Comment: I did 2 simple modifications. If I change 'UBound(arr) <> 2' to 'UBound(arr) <> 3' and click 'Hide' button, VBA page is shown yielding message 'Object required'. If I change password to "ab", macro does not recognize this. So I guess script is not getting that far.

I would conclude macro is executed from the button but exited prematurely.

Comment: I included a messagebox right below 'arr=Split .. '

It returns value '3'

    Dim strString
    strString = "UBound of button is: " & UBound(arr) & vbCrLf
    MsgBox strString

Comment: Tim, this is excellent !! Show and Hide both work. Also a second set of buttons works.

Thank you very much (also for your patience).

Comment: OK glad you finally got it working - couple of mistakes on my part: I should never edit code in the answer without testing it!